# Replacing Pandas series substrings with elements of the same index from other lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, substring

**Context**

I have a pandas dataframe that contains 3 columns.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'c1': ['blah testing1 blah', 'hello1 world'], 
    'c2': ['testing1', 'hello1'], 
    'c3': ['testingggg', 'heeello']
})
```

`c1` contains arbitrary strings, `c2` contains words found in `c1`, and `c3` contains words that will replace the corresponding words in `c1` but they differ in a random length.

**Ideal output**

For each row I want to find the word that is in `c2` within the `c1` text and then replace the first instance of that substring that is an exact match with the word in `c3`. I want this output to be in a new `c4`.

e.g.

```
c1: 'blah testing1 blah', 
c2: 'testing1', 
c3: 'testingggg', 
c4: 'blah testingggg blah'
```

**What I currently have**

```py
# initialize the new column to contain the original text
df['c4'] = df['c1']

for i in range(len(df['c1'])):
    original_word = df['c2'].loc[i]
    replacement_word = df['c3'].loc[i]
    df['replaced_utterance'][i] = df['replaced_utterance'][i].replace(original_word, replacement_word)
```

But this seems to not actually update anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:
to replace all occurrences

```py
df['c4'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[0].replace(x[1], x[2]), axis=1)
```

to replace only 1 (or x) occurrences

```py
df['c4'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[0].replace(x[1], x[2], 1), axis=1)
```

Result:

```py
    c1                  c2          c3          c4
0   blah testing1 blah  testing1    testingggg  blah testingggg blah
1   hello1 world        hello1      heeello     heeello world
```

Comment: great thank you! It does look like I'm getting an output in `c4` where it is replacing all instances of the `c2` word and not just the first. How would I modify to only look at the first?

Comment: I've edited the answer with the code to replace only the first occurrence